# https outbound connections work before creating AMI, but not on new instance using that AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl, amazon-ami

- On Amazon Web Services
- Launch an EC2 instance using Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.1 - ami-fb8e9292 (64-bit)
- Run my ansible script to configure the server for baking into an AMI
- Run some Ruby that accesses an https:// url. It works fine.
- Create the AMI from this image
- Create a new instance from that AMI
- Run the same Ruby
- Expect it to work, got this error instead:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed>

- The cert directories appear to be identical when I ls -l them side-by-side

How can I make the instance work as expected? Thank you.

Comment: Check is there's any difference testing the SSL certificate with openssl and going to one server or the other: `echo -n | openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect google.com:443 -CApath /usr/share/ssl-cert` (replace google.com with your hostnames)

Comment: As per my previous comment, google.com was just an example placeholder, don't use google.com and intead replace first with one server's hostname and run, then the other

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood. This machine isn't a server; it's a worker. It's failing on outbound https: connections. I'll update the question to remove the noise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems AWS router tunnels SSLv3 outbound connection through TLS for older instances. Nevertheless it is recommended to switch to TLS:

```
  ....
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
```